# Link a static library to object in cmake

Tags: gcc, cmake

I am trying to compile a project using cmake. I need to use an external static library in `src1.c` so I utilized `target_link_libraries` to link it to the object file. However, I am getting some complains about missing functions in `src1.c` which should be in the external library.

```
add_library(input_output OBJECT
        src/src1.c
        src/src2.c
        src/src3.c)

find_library(EXTERNAL_LIB NAMES libexternallib.a PATHS ~/lib)

target_link_libraries(input_output PRIVATE
        "${EXTERNAL_LIB}")
```

So I am not sure what I should do at this point. the logic sounds right at least

**UPDATE1**: I also added the external library directly into the linker command

```
add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra --std=c99 -L~/lib -lexternallib)
add_link_options(-L~/lib -lexternallib)
```

but this added the library flags before the object file for the linker command, which leads to some other problem with [ordering the linker arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/why-does-the-order-in-which-libraries-are-linked-sometimes-cause-errors-in-gcc)

Comment: Please, add **exact error message** to the question post.

Comment: src1.c:(.text+0x3c): undefined reference to `some_function'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Error "Undefined reference" can be issued only when link an executable or a shared library. Creation of the OBJECT library doesn't involve linking, so it cannot issue given error. Please, provide **more detailed description** of your case.

Comment: Correct, the problem happens when I want to link input_output to an executable target:

`add_executable(my_app app/main_app.c)
target_link_libraries(my_app input_output)
`

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what is really the reason for your error here, but I'll give it a try.

First of all, you don't need to link manually with add_compile_options or add_link_options. The cmake command target_link_libraries is doing that for you.

What I could imagine, because of the missing functions, that you need to add a header include directory from the dependency.

e.g.:

```
target_include_directories(input_output PRIVATE /path/to/external_library_header)
```

Comment: I have added the header file, the problem is not compilation in fact! the main issue is the linker